# Visual studio designer view not displaying correctly after upgrade to windows 10?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, windows-10, windows-7-x64, windows-forms-designer

So, I have a form in VS2010 I was working on in Windows 7 that looked like this :

[image]

But when my IT department upgraded my pc, and look in the designer view it looks like this, AND the form is much smaller, everything seems to run into each other :

[image]

At runtime, the image looks correct like the first image. I have made sure my display settings look correct, and my designer code has not changed between Monday (before upgrade) and Today (post upgrade). Has anyone run into a similar issue? If so, what was your resolution?

Comment: By the way, I did not have to reinstall VS2010 or anything, it was good to go when I got it back from my IT department, and I have not tried that yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the answer. If you go to control panel > display > 'Set a custom scaling level', you may notice that the custom scaling level is set to 125% or higher. I changed that back to 100%, and then updated, and it fixed my display completely. We are now back to normal.

Comment: Some of it is probably related to the fact that controls just *look different* in Windows 10, checkboxes and buttons, for instance, have way more padding and different chrome.